# OpenLDAP: How to hide config directory from tools like JXplorer, etc

Tags: database, authentication, openldap, configuration

I'm trying to set up an OpenLDAP server for test and demonstration purposes - my team need to be add LDAP connectivity to our product, so we want to have an LDAP server we can authenticate against. 
Unfortunately it's not enough to be able to develop and test authentication and authorisation against LDAP people and groups. We also need to be able to demonstrate this capability to prospective customers. At these demonstrations we need to be able to show the LDAP tree in a browser such as JXplorer. 
My problem is that since the config database and any user database must start with distinct namingContexts, two entries with different domains appear in JXplorer (or any other browser) when a connection is established. How can I hide the config database in this case? I have been looking at editing the Access Control List, but most examples I have seen are concerned just with denying access to specific attributes...

Answer (score 1):

```
dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
olcAccess: {0}to * by * none
```

will permit only `olcRootDN` of `olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config` to do anything with the database `cn=config`. `olcRootDN` is never subjected to access restirctions.

From [OpenLDAP's documentation on ACLs](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html):

> There are two special pseudo attributes entry and children. To read
>   (and hence return) a target entry, the subject must have read access
>   to the target's entry attribute. To perform a search, the subject must
>   have search access to the search base's entry attribute. To add or
>   delete an entry, the subject must have write access to the entry's
>   entry attribute AND must have write access to the entry's parent's
>   children attribute. To rename an entry, the subject must have write
>   access to entry's entry attribute AND have write access to both the
>   old parent's and new parent's children attributes. The complete
>   examples at the end of this section should help clear things up.
>
> Lastly, there is a special entry selector * that is used to select
>   any entry. It is used when no other  selector has been provided.
>   It's equivalent to "dn=.*"

Answer (score 0):

Just fill in the Base DN field of the JXplorer connection dialog for the database you want to demonstrate, and save it as a template. Then JXplorer will only show the LDAP tree for that base DN.